# chefのレシピ内で外部ライブラリが使いたい時の呼び出し場所

Tags: chef

Chefのレシピ内で`active_support`が使いたかったので

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

と `site-cookbooks/mycookbook/recipes/default.rb` の初めに記述して
正常に読み込みが行われてるのを確認したのですが本当にこの方法であってるかどうかの自信がありません。

この方法であっているのでしょうか？ もっと適切な方法があればご教示ください。